# Issue while posting Array and Form data together through jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have been trying to post Array and Form data together but seems like I am getting JavaScript errors. When I tried to post Only array data without adding form data it works fine.
I am having a Dropdown Select Box and few CheckBoxes. I wanted to post SelectBox data and CheckBox data together, so I had saved the CheckBox data's into array since it is a multi Select CheckBox.

In the below code i need to resolve issue with this

```
data: datasel+"&id="+$("#member_id").val(), //Error in this line only. To be Fixed!!
```

Here is the Complete code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
     $("#submit_issueBook").click(function(){
         //Creating Array and adding data
        var datasel = { 'selector[]' : []};
        $(":checked").each(function() {
          datasel['selector[]'].push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/issue_book.php",
            //data: "submit_addMember="+$("#submit_addMember").val(),  <-- Default format for sending post data
            data: datasel+"&id="+$("#member_id").val(),
                if($.trim(html)=='true'){
                    $("#err").addClass("alert alert-success err-inline");
                    $("#err").html("<strong>Member details updated Successfully</strong>");
                    window.location="<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>";
                }
                else{
                    $("#err").addClass("alert alert-danger err-inline");
                    $("#err").html("<img src='images/caution-icon.png' />"+$.trim(html));
                }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
                $("#err").css('display', '-webkit-inline-box', 'important');
                $("#err").addClass("err-inline");
                $("#err").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' /> Loading...")
           }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP code to catch this data is

```
if( isset( $_POST['selector'] ) )
{   $id=$_POST['id'];
    $data=$_POST['selector'];
    for ( $i=0; $i < count( $data ); $i++ )
    {
        //Some SQL query
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing json with get string in data. As you have datasel object, just add id key and value to it. First drop those square brackets, it is only needed in html form as a name:

```
var datasel = { 'selector' : []};
```

then in the loop:

```
datasel['selector'].push($(this).val());
```

after loop add id key/value pair to datasel object:

```
datasel.id = $("#member_id").val();
```

And then in ajax it is enough to send this json:

```
data: datasel,
```

Comment: Thanks Bro it worked. But one problem I have checked the POST data it seems it is posting one extra select here

    selector"%"5B"%"5D=2&selector"%"5B"%"5D=1&selector"%"5B"%"5D=2&id=2

The one with selector=2 in the first is automatically added dont know how. I have even checked the html there is no such problem in that. Then why it is posting two times selector=2

Comment: I cannot know, looks like you have two "2"s checked. Double check your form inputs set.

Comment: Thanks Man I had figured out the issue replaced $(":checked") with $("#selection:checked")

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you put the DOM manipulation code into the ajax call settings? Try out this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/issue_book.php",
    //data: "submit_addMember="+$("#submit_addMember").val(),  <-- Default format for sending post data
    data: datasel+"&id="+$("#member_id").val(),
    beforeSend:function()
    {
        $("#err").css('display', '-webkit-inline-box', 'important');
        $("#err").addClass("err-inline");
        $("#err").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' /> Loading...")
    }
});
```

What I did here is deleted this code I mentioned before (so you should put it where you need) and then put beforeSend inside the ajax settings where it belongs :)

Hop it will help you.